# How To Change The Color Of A Text Function Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a text function like this:
`text = "Text Here"`
in Python 3, and I was wondering how I could (or if it was even possible) to allow that text function to use color like in `print`.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: `text = "Text Here"` is not a function, is a variable.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean with:  "to allow that text function to use color". Can you be clearer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I mean, you can use color in print like this: ```from color import colored print (colored("Text Here", 'color')``` and that gives you whatever color you want. But I want it to work with texts. Would it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print colored text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are online sites that can give you the answer to this question. An example of text color in python would be `print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n")`. The code for colors are:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuEna.png)

That is the table for the color codes.
I hope this helps and that your question is answered! (: